# Run perl script on remote server

Tags: perl, remote-server

Is it possible to run perl script, which is located on a remote server, on that server from Windows? There is a job on a remote server that I want to get done every time I make something on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have *something* listening for an instruction to run the script, and then you have to send the instruction.

There are lots of approaches you could take to that, including:

- Running an SSH server and then connecting to it from an ssh client on the windows machine
- Running an HTTP server, running the script through FastCGI, and then requesting the URL for it from `curl` or a browser on the Windows machine
- Writing a custom protocol, listening on a socket, and then writing a custom client that you run on the Windows machine

Comment: psexec is a reasonable alternative to ssh (on a windows machine)

Comment: When PowerShell 6 is available, it can run on Linux/UNIX systems. `Invoke-Command` can run commands on remote machines. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

You can use `plink` to run commands on the server from Windows, assuming the server is running `sshd`.

```
plink user@a.domain.ext echo hi
```

This will print "hi\n" to the standard output.

Substitute `/path/to/perl/script` for `echo` above and substitute `hi` with any command line argument that the script needs.

`plink` is available here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

One cautionary personal note from doing this many times is that the environment in which the perl script will be run is much less complete than what you would experience when logging in via a full SSH session and running the command interactively. Many environment variables you would normally expect are unset.

For instance using "set | wc -l" in the command above produces only 39 environment variables defined, but from an interactive SSH session, there are 57 environment variables defined. You have to make sure your perl script isn't depending on an environment variable that hasn't been set. For instance, you may need to use full paths for any modules that it uses, or by using the `-I` flag in the shebang line, because `@INC` may not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: Assuming said server is running sshd .